# Ubuntu 20.04 : Sound not always coming through headphone

Tags: 20.04

Hi I have come across a peculiar problem in my cherry tail laptop made by rdp.in ( a startup in india) After shutdown when i bootup sound in speaker a little distorted and when i insert my headphone there are no sound in headphone except a buzz. Then after removing headphone sound not coming through laptop speaker. So what i have done far i use `alsactl restore` and reboot and everything seems works fine( i don't know why) But after a shutdown problem starts again. It is really very annoying that after every fresh start i have to restart the laptop with `alsactl restore`.
I have tried to save asound.state by

```
sudo alsactl --file asound.state store
sudo cp asound.state /var/lib/alsa/asound.state
```

But no help. After every shutdown problem starts again. Help pls.

this is my system config:

> 00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor
>   x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series SoC Transaction Register (rev 36)
>     Subsystem: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor
>   x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series SoC Transaction Register  Flags: bus
>   master, fast devsel, latency 0    Kernel driver in use: iosf_mbi_pci
>
> 00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation
>   Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Integrated
>   Graphics Controller (rev 36) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
>     DeviceName:  Onboard IGD    Subsystem: Intel Corporation
>   Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Integrated
>   Graphics Controller   Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ
>   165   Memory at 90000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]    Memory
>   at 80000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]    I/O ports at f000
>   [size=64]     Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [virtual] [disabled] [size=128K]
>     Capabilities:    Kernel driver in use: i915  Kernel
>   modules: i915
>
> 00:03.0 Multimedia controller: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium
>   Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series Imaging Unit (rev 36)
>     Subsystem: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor
>   x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series Imaging Unit  Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 255
>     Memory at 91000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [virtual] [size=4M]
>     Capabilities:    Kernel driver in use:
>   intel_atomisp2_pm     Kernel modules: intel_atomisp2_pm
>
> 00:0b.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation
>   Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series Power
>   Management Controller (rev 36)    Subsystem: Intel Corporation
>   Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series Power
>   Management Controller     Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 164     Memory at 9183b000
>   (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]  Capabilities: 
>     Kernel driver in use: proc_thermal  Kernel modules:
>   processor_thermal_device
>
> 00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium
>   Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series USB xHCI Controller (rev 36)
>   (prog-if 30 [XHCI])   Subsystem: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium
>   Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series USB xHCI Controller     Flags: bus
>   master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 117     Memory at 91800000 (64-bit,
>   non-prefetchable) [size=64K]  Capabilities:    Kernel
>   driver in use: xhci_hcd
>
> 00:1a.0 Encryption controller: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium
>   Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series Trusted Execution Engine (rev
>   36)   Subsystem: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor
>   x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series Trusted Execution Engine  Flags: bus
>   master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 163   Memory at 91700000 (32-bit,
>   non-prefetchable) [size=1M]   Memory at 91600000 (32-bit,
>   non-prefetchable) [size=1M]   Capabilities:    Kernel
>   driver in use: mei_txe    Kernel modules: mei_txe
>
> 00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor
>   x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series PCU (rev 36)  Subsystem: Intel Corporation
>   Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series PCU    Flags:
>   bus master, medium devsel, latency 0  Capabilities: 
>     Kernel driver in use: lpc_ich   Kernel modules: lpc_ich

Comment: One edit i just noticed that if i boot with headphone plugged in things working well. This time also i dont know why? Though this way out may need a little bit more testing..